# White space pattern matching using sed

Tags: bash, sed, pattern-matching

I am writing a bash script to replace a pattern in a line containing white space.
Text looks like this - 
property name="abcd" value="1234" and the value changes multiple times in the file like value=3456 and value=3689. Only the line containing name="abcd" and value=something something should be replaced.

There are other instance where abcd and value are called separately which should NOT be replaced.

I want to match both criteria name="abcd" and value before doing replacement. Something like

```
sed -i '/name="abcd" value=/c\property name="abcd" value="set"' filename
```

How do I resolve that whitespace between "abcd" and value so that sed can recognize it as a single string?

Input:

```
`property name="abcd" value="1234"`
`property name="abcd" value="73845"`
`property name="abcd" value="8276"`
`property name="qwerty" value="1234"`
`blah blah ${abcd} blah`
```

Desired output:

```
`property name="abcd" value="set"`
`property name="abcd" value="set"`
`property name="abcd" value="set"`
`property name="qwerty" value="1234"`
`blah blah ${abcd} blah`
```

Comment: In other words you want to replace `1234` and others by `blank` ?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but you should *probably* be using an XML parser . . .

Comment: Yes, replace the value with the string Blank for all instances matching the criteria

Comment: The only common pattern for all the lines is name="abcd" value. I want to match that pattern and do  a line replacement

Comment: Please add an example of input and desired output.

Comment: added input and output

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have name="blah" value="blah" on seperate lines, and want to just remove the \n

```
    sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
```

would do what you want taken from [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)

Comment: No, value is different on each line. I want that to be replaced by the string "blah"

Answer (score 0):

After a few trial and errors, I hit upon the solution

```
`sed -i "/V.prop.*value=/c\ <property name=\\\"V.prop\\\" value=\\\"set\\\"/>" filename`
```

The .* fills in between the two search patterns in the same line. The \\ is used for escaping double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -i -r 's/(property name="abcd" value=)"[0-9]+"/\1"set"/' filename
```